# Surjections from free groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, free-groups

I am stuck on the following:

How do I go about finding surjections from the free group of rank 2 $\mathbb{F}_2 = \mathbb{ Z∗Z}$, to the finite group of two elements $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Also, how would I also prove that this list is complete?

any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What relations does the nontrivial element of $\Bbb Z_2$ satisfy?

Comment: @Bryan it's just the standard Z mod 2 group

Comment: Hint: The set of maps are entirely determined by the map of the generators of $\mathbb F_2$ to $\mathbb Z_2$. It is surjective if one of the generators goes to the non-identity element of $\mathbb Z_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, when you're looking for surjections $G\twoheadrightarrow H$, the best thing to do is look at possible kernels $K\unlhd G$, as you will have $G/K\cong H$. These won't always necessarily give you all the information you need, but they can certainly narrow it down. In particular, since $H$ has order $2$, you want to look for normal subgroups of $\mathbb{F}_2$ that have index $2$.  As Thomas Andrews suggests, the easiest way is to find them is to use images of the generators.  If you are still stuck, see if you can find the normal subgroups, and then you can try to contrive maps of the generators that will give you the right kernels.

Comment: sorry for the late reply and thank you for the answer! I am stil however stuck on this question, i know that there are 2 generators namely $1_L$ and $1_R$ for each $\mathbb{Z}$ in the free group i was thinking the homomorphisms could map $1_L$ to 1, or $1_R$ to 1 or both $1_L$ and $1_R$ to 1, where $1 \in \mathbb{Z}_2$. would i be write in saying this?